# How to record Android device's screen on Android version below 4.4 (KitKat)

Tags: android, adb

With Android version  4.4 (KitKat) one can  record Android device's screen with following command using ADB from  commandline.

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

But this only works in Android version  4.4 (KitKat) and 5.0 (Lolipop)

Is there any other command or a way to record a video below Android version  4.4 (KitKat) using ADB?

Comment: I think you can only do this if you root the phone. Then there are several programs on the app store that say they will record your screen.

Comment: I would suggest you to try this solution. Connect your phone to PC. Before that enable USB debugging and install some an app who will "Mirror" your display to PC. There is an app called Droid@Screen with who you'll have your display on PC,and you'll control the whole cell phone with mouse and keyboard. Then you can record your display of PC with numerous software,who are free too.
I hope I helped a little bit. :)

Comment: If you are willing to skip the "using ADB" part, and you have a device that has MHL, SlimPort, Miracast, Intel WiDi, or HDMI output capability, there are HDMI recording devices available that you can try.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**This only work in KitKat and via ADB only. This does not work below Kitkat.**

To start recording your device’s screen, run the following command:

`adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/example.mp4`, This command will start recording your device’s screen using the default settings and save the resulting video to a file at `/sdcard/example.mp4` file on your device.

When you’re done recording, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the Command Prompt window to stop the screen recording. You can then find the screen recording file at the location you specified. Note that the screen recording is saved to your device’s internal storage, not to your computer.

The default settings are to use your device’s standard screen resolution, encode the video at a bitrate of 4Mbps, and set the maximum screen recording time to 180 seconds. For more information about the command-line options you can use, run the following command:

`adb shell screenrecord --help`,
This works without rooting the device. Hope this helps.

Comment: Then you just need to run this command to download the file on your computer:
`adb pull /sdcard/example.mp4 .` and this to delete it:
`adb shell rm /sdcard/example.mp4`

Comment: should be --help, not -help

Comment: Ctrl-C forces the process to close immediately/ or the SIGTERM is going to the inner screenrecord process. The video is not saved/ flushed. Any way to ensure the video is saved? On ubuntu. If I use the Time parameter it works, but do not want to crop the file later/ have to short a file.

Comment: Ctrl+z on linux doesn't seem rigth to me.

Comment: Yeah ... `CTRL+Z` will suspend the process ... I'm pretty sure it's `CTRL+C` everywhere. That's what I've been doing.

Comment: An answer that doesn't answer.

Comment: @Lime use Ctrl + \ on Linux.

Answer (score 17):

1. `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/video.mp4` #save MP4
2. `Ctrl+C`  #Stop record
3. `adb pull /sdcard/video.mp4` #pull mp4 to your pc
4. `adb shell rm /sdcard/video.mp4` #Delete file on phone

Comment: Is there a way to put this into a bash function that doesn't result in the final file being corrupted?

Comment: @sbearben You need to wait after #Stop record and before pull. If you use windows batch (cmd) - just add 'timeout 3' to fait for 3 sec.

Answer (score 4):

As you pointed out, that command is **only available in KitKat** and via ADB only.

I'd say your best option is recording the portion of the screen of an emulator (either AVD or [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)).

Answer (score 2):

[AirServer](http://airserver.com) is a good application to do this with. You can mirror your device's screen to your PC/Mac and record them to a file. Great quality too.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid time limit issue, you can use this snippet:

```
./adb exec-out "while true; do screenrecord --bit-rate=16m --output-format=h264 --size 720x1280 --time-limit 180 -; done" | ffplay -framerate 60 -framedrop -bufsize 16M -
```

Comment: Is this snippet truncated? Also, what's `ffplay`?

Answer (score 0):

The screenrecord command is a shell utility for recording the display of devices running Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher.

Ref. : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html (Recording a device screen)

**OR**

There is many application available on market for screen recording, So download which more is useful to you.