# How to record Android device screen(before KitKat) connected to computer via USB?

Tags: android, windows, screenshot, android-4.2-jelly-bean, screen-recording

I have already searched a lot for an answer over the internet such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217333/how-to-record-android-devices-screen-on-android-version-below-4-4-kitkat) question, but didn't found an answer.

I want to record my Android device's screen connected to computer via USB for some kind of automation thing. I found [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-screen-recording) that Google has created an utility for this but only for versions starting from KitKat.

Are there any other possible ***utilities*** or ***scripts*** for Windows computer through which I can achieve what I want to do? It should save the resulting video file either on my device or my computer on which it is connected to.

P.S.- I also found that this can be somehow achieved by using [javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) library. But i was unable to compile and run all of its sources, so it didn't worked for me until now.

Comment: @LisaMM Thanks for suggesting edit to my question and correcting it.

Comment: Is the device rooted?

Comment: @Robert No, but you can help for rooted device in case nothing for unrooted devices.

Comment: There are dozen of screen recording aps in the play store (most require root for older devices). Whats wrong with them?

Comment: @Robert I don't need apps, i need some code or script which i can trigger from my code in order to achieve same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [androidscreencast](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/).

**Summary:** Desktop app to control an android device remotely using mouse and keyboard. Should work on Windows/Linux/MacOS with any android device.

**Features:**

- Mouse and keyboard control (FOR ROOTED DEVICES ONLY)
- Landscape mode (right click)
- **Video recording** <---- No Root required
- Basic file browser

Note: Video FPS is low.

Comment: Thanks for your help, This was something i was needing. I will look into its source code. I am sure I will be able to invoke this from my code. What are your views on it(if you have looked into it)? Thank again. :)

Comment: I didn't look at the source so can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Best tool for screenshots/casts is the recently released AndroidTool:
https://github.com/mortenjust/androidtool-mac

Unfortunately it's only for Mac.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Its really helpfull but currently I am working on Windows. I will surely look into it too. Thank you.