# How to capture every frame in ARCore

Tags: java, android, arcore, screen-capture

Is there any solution to capture every SceneView in ARCore as array of bitmap or something like that?
I want to save every frame which is captured by ARCamera for processing them in the future.

The problem is that with the current code, I have a heavy performance load which first slows the application and then it leads to an application crash.
I'm new to android/ Java and I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

Aside from that, something else is surprising.
When I log the takePhoto() function inner block which is responsible for copying ARSenceview into bitmapsarray, difference of time stamps of every function call is not the same and equal to 1s/30frames, though it is very important for me to capture the views at a fix ratio.

When the application is in capturing mode, I call this function every frame. One possible error should because of high number of threads acquire here.

```java
    private void takePhoto()
    {
        view = arFragment.getArSceneView();

        // NOTE: Create a handler thread to offload the processing of the image
        final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("PixelCopier");
        handlerThread.start();

        // NOTE: Make request to copy
        PixelCopy.request(view, bitmap, copyResult -> {
            if(copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS)
            {
                bitmapsBuffer[bufferIndex] = bitmap;
                bufferIndex++;
                if(bufferIndex == 120)
                {
                    bufferIndex = 0;
                    FlushBitmapsBuffer();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                messenger.message("Failed to copyPixel: " + copyResult);
            }
            handlerThread.quitSafely();
        }, new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()));
    }
```

Then after collecting 120 frames I try to write the temporary array of bitmaps on SD using another service.

```java
    private void FlushBitmapsBuffer()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataCopyService.class);
        intent.putExtra("BitmapsBuffer", bitmapsBuffer);
        intent.putExtra("StorageDataRoot",
                storageData.getRootDir());
        intent.putExtra("StorageDataProj",
                storageData.getProjectDir().getAbsolutePath());
        startService(intent);
    }
```

the service works as follow:

```java
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        messenger.log("Service " + TAG + " started.");

        bitmapsBuffer = (Bitmap[]) intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("BitmpasBuffer");

        File file;
        file = new File(intent.getStringExtra("StorageDataRoot"));
        storageData.setRootDir(file);
        file = new File(intent.getStringExtra("StorageDataProj"));
        storageData.setProjectDir(file);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                messenger.log("Service inner thread.");
                // Save the data here using a file manager class
                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

Does someone have any idea about what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, thank's for the edit.

Comment: Do you need every frame to be a uncompressed bitmap or can that be substituted with video (H.263/H.264)?

Comment: @MorrisonChang based on what I require a uncompressed bitmap is better but right now I want to capture a H.264 video and then extract its frames using `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever`.

Comment: Unclear if you've already looked at [adb shell screenrecord](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28217333/295004) or the other options listed in [Screen recording of specific views in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46497611/295004)

Comment: Yea, but it won't help me in the long-term, actually in the end I don't need what currently is getting draw on the view. The raw data for my further  process is what the ARCoreCamera is capturing. So I don't need to capture things like UI, ARRenderableObjects, etc.

Comment: @MorrisonChang right now the most important thing for me is to figure out if I'm messing with thread handlers and that service class. I'm not sure what causes the program to stop. Tracing the logcat, I reach to `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: PixelCopier
    Process: " ", PID: 25977
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob.` when the app crashes. Seems something is wrong when I want to pass the bitmapsarray. P.S:  I can't get log from the service which means the application crashes somewhere before / while startService(intent) function in FlushBitmapsBuffer().

Answer (score 1):

Capturing frames using Sceneform is supported [SceneView.startMirroringToSurface()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/SceneView#startMirroringToSurface(android.view.Surface,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).  This will render the current view to a surface every frame.

It is used in the [Video Recording Sample](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/videorecording) to capture a video.